# Python re.compile - select all files with any image file extension (regex)

Tags: python, regex

In a portion of a Python script, I'm trying to select all images with formats such as the examples below:

`customImage0.jpg`
`customImage1.png`
`customImage3.gif`

I currently have this code:

`pattern = re.compile('customImage[0-9]*.png')`

I want to modify it so I can select all image extension types, not just `png`. I've  tried `[jpg|png|gif|tiff]`. That grabbed only the first letter of the file extension:

`customImage0.j`
`customImage1.p`

How do I grab the whole file extension?

Comment: See "Groups > non-capture group" in the linked question's top answer.

Comment: `customImage[0-9]*\.(?:jpg|png|gif|tiff)`

Comment: When you say "that" grabbed... What exactly is that? I'm getting the expected results with your code using pattern.match(<file>)